# Nuclear Energy Depletion in Solar System

Tags: nuclear-physics

Lets keep this simple. Lets assume that the amount of known fissionable material is fixed.

Lets assume that energy demand is the same for 2015, from now until depletion, to keep it simpler.

How long would at current usage rate would we run out of Uranium-235/Plutonium-239 to run nuclear energy plants?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really an economics question.

Comment: @CuriousOne How is exactly this an economic question? Especially considering that Uranium 235 lifetime decay rate which is part of physic.

Comment: I interpret this question to be asking how long the U-235 would last if all deposits have been found and are easily accessible. I see this more as an amount vs. rate used problem then some open-ended monster, although there may be some difficulty obtaining an actual number for the starting amount.

Comment: @CoilKid: "easily accessible" _is_ an economics question. Most of the uranium is probably in the core. Are you going to get it? How much is that going to cost?

Comment: @CuriousOne Be that as it may, this is a simple question. He's not considering the economic implications, I don't believe. When doing a thought experiment, one usually simplifies things. Think of the popular physics simplification "Assume a frictionless vacuum". That won't ever happen, so why do we do it anyway?

Comment: @CoilKid: You can't answer the question without economics and with economics you will get a random result. The only rational answer is that we will never run out of fissionable materials. Stop worrying.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very naive way of looking at it. Natural resources are rarely ever "fixed". There are deposits that are cheap to mine, more deposits that are expensive to mine and unlimited deposits that are too expensive to mine. Why unlimited? Because a deposit that is too expensive will never be mined and it will always be available when you will never need it.

Uranium is one of those deposits that will never run out. You can have as much of it as you ever will not want to buy at prices that will be way above those of cheaper energy sources.

What's a cheaper energy source? Solar energy. That won't run out for hundreds of billions of years (but you would have to survive the cataclysmic event that would happen before the white dwarf phase). I hope that's long enough.

Comment: Then again, nuclear is something we have *now* that's capable of meeting energy demands whereas solar is something that would have to cover entire continents to meet demands (assuming current efficiency). Also, may I remind everyone of the energy density of U-235 with [this handy XKCD chart](https://xkcd.com/1162/)?

Comment: I may have exaggerated the continents thing. It *probably* wouldn't have to cover continents. I don't remember the actual coverage requirement just off the top of my head.

Comment: @CoilKid: Energy comes at a cost and that makes it a matter of economics. We have basically stopped developing nuclear power because it has become too expensive. Solar energy, on the other hand, is falling in price exponentially. The energy density of the fuel is irrelevant when you have to build a giant cement sarcophagus around it to contain the corium  when things go wrong. The only future use of nuclear energy will be spacecraft (no radiation shielding needed, open reactors are just fine) and that will be miniscule.

Comment: Not quite... Uranium decay into other atoms. There are fewer atom that has more proton and can decay into something fissionable. Eventually there will be no more "usable Uranium 235". The most common source of those material are super nova. I am pretty sure we have to be capable of FTL travel first to have a snowball chance to harvest those.

Comment: @Coilkid: The limits to energy production on Earth are given by climate change. We will never produce as much energy as we could because the planet can't handle it.

Comment: @Vyndicu: You need to think about this some more. How much one uses of something is not a matter of physical limits. It's a matter of money (and I already said that this doesn't belong on this site). We will never use "all of anything" because that's too expensive. Having said that, if you want to learn something about physics, start thinking about just how large a number $6\times 10^{24}$ is. That's the mass of Earth in kg. Nobody will ever mine trough that much mass to begin with, for whatever reason. No supernovae necessary.

Comment: @CuriousOne That climate limitation on solar energy doesn't applies to satellites or on moon. Which will receive much more energy since none of it is being reflected by ozone layer.  Grant the heat alone from transferring colossal amount of energy could be potentially dangerous.

Comment: @CuriousOne Are you serious? Are you going to compare "regular water" as the same thing as a fissionable Uranium-235? Because Earth has LOT of it but relative VERY little Uranium (including all isotopes). Quote: Of the ten largest uranium mines in the world (Mc Arthur River, Ranger, Rossing, Kraznokamensk, Olympic Dam, Rabbit Lake, Akouta, Arlit, Beverly, and McClean Lake), by 2020, six will be depleted, two will be in their final stages, one will be upgrading and one will be producing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_uranium

Comment: @Vyndicu: Population satellites: 3-6. Population Moon: 0. Your original question was about current usage rates. Don't move the goalpost.

Comment: I am NOT moving the goal post of the question. I was responding to your climate limitation on collecting solar energy which has nothing to do with Uranium usage rate. Look up.

Comment: @Vyndicu: Peak uranium is caused by decrease in demand, not limits of production. Peak anything is economics, by the way, just as I said. :-)

Comment: @Vyndicu: You are the one who keeps moving the economics argument... I just pointed out to you that this is economics and not physics.

Comment: Peak usage has nothing to do with depleted rate. The same way oil field can be eventually depleted and has nothing to do with peak usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39989/discussion-between-curiousone-and-vyndicu).